# Using regex to replace with smarty?

Tags: php, regex, smarty

I think that I should be using Regex to do this replacing in the Smarty template system, but I'm not sure.  Here's the original output:

```
<input type=hidden name=item_name value="My Website - Invoice #53">
```

Here's what is currently shows:

```
<input type=hidden name=item_name value="My Website - Payment For Online Service - #53">
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
{$code|replace:'My Website - Invoice':'My Website - Payment For Online Service - '}
```

All I want to do is remove the numbers at the end, but each invoice ID is different.  Here's what I want it:

```
<input type=hidden name=item_name value="My Website - Payment For Online Service">
```

Does anyone know how I can use Regex or anything else to remove the numbers at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `\d+` to match one or more digits,

```
{$code|replace:'My Website - Invoice\s+#\d+':'My Website - Payment For Online Service'}
```